# При попытке подключиться к сайту для парсинга происходит ошибка 403

Tags: python, парсер

В результате `print(r)` в консоль выводит `<Response [403]>` , из-за чего это происходит? Как к нему подключится?

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
from fake_useragent import UserAgent


session = HTMLSession()
name ='floppa_b'
head = {"User-Agent": UserAgent().chrome}
r = session.get('https://www.faceit.com/ru/players/' + str(name) + '/stats/csgo', headers=head)
print(r)
```

Comment: Вам в явном виде приходит ответ http что вам доступ запрещен. Не авторизованы вы для этой информации. Никак это не обойти, если вы не собрались взламывать сайт.

Comment: Тюе сайт не впускает меня т.к я не авторизован? Может просто авторизоваться?

Comment: Вы путаете авторизацию и аутентификацию. Аутентификация - это когда вы вводите логин пароль, и система подтверждает что вы - это вы. Пока не зашли - ошибка будет 401. А авторизация и ошибка 403 - это что именно у вас нет прав на эту страницу (например они есть у админов, а вы простой пользователь) . Возможно в некоторых случаях после логин-пароля у вас станет хватать прав, но  это не гарантированно